# how to preselect an association checkbox using simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, associations, simple-form

I have this piece of code, while using `simple_form`:

```
= simple_form_for :report do |f|
  = f.association :presets,
    :collection => @account.presets.collect{ |p| [p.name, p.id] },
    :as => :check_boxes
```

How can I preselect a specific `preset` checkbox, knowing that the ID of this `preset` is passed within `params[:preset_id]`? The checkboxes' HTML `name` attributes are `report[preset_ids][]`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the simple_form documentation:

> The association helper just invokes
>   input under the hood, so all options
>   available to :select, :radio and
>   :check_boxes are also available to
>   association. Additionally, you can
>   specify the collection by hand, all
>   together with the prompt:
>
> ```
>    f.association :company, :collection
>       => Company.active.all(:order => 'name'), :prompt => "Choose a Company"
> ```

So, you should use something like this:

```
= simple_form_for :report do |f|
  = f.association :presets,
    :collection => @account.presets.collect{ |p| [p.name, p.id] },
    :as => :check_boxes,
    :checked => params[:preset_id]
```

I don't have experience with simple_form, but this might help :)

Answer (score 25):

An update for everybody. the :selected option did not work for me. I used:

```
:checked => [2, 3]
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Same for me. :selected doesn't work and :checked does.  Which does make sense when we're creating check boxes and not selectors!

Answer (score 1):

f.association Really did the trick, thanks :), for preselecting, saving, and everything, I don't have reputation enough to vote up your answer (@claudio-acciaresi) that's why I'm commenting here...

This is my snippet:

```
<%= f.association :association, collection: Model.all, 
      value_method: :id, label_method: :name, 
      as: :check_boxes, include_blank: false %>
```

Replace symbol :association with the current has_many from the model.
Replace Model.all, for your source data.

Hope it gets useful for someone else :)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to cast params[:preset_id] to integer:

```
params[:preset_id].to_i
```