# rails multiple checkboxes in 1 db column. saves correctly but doesn't show as checked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, simple-form

Event saves the section id's in an array. But in the `/events/1/edit` view for a newly created event, the expected checkboxes are not checked. I'm guessing because the default for checkbox values is booleans.

`Event.last.newsletters #=> ["108", "115", "116", "117", "118", ""]`

I have a CRUD for Event. Each Event can belong to multiple Sections. I have this displayed as a collection of checkboxes with the simpleform gem.

```
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
...
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :newsletters, Section.all, :id, :name, :input_html => { :class => 'checkbox' } %>
```

This results in the following html:

```
<span><input id="event_newsletters_1" name="event[newsletters][]" type="checkbox" value="1" /><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="event_newsletters_1">Newsletter 1</label></span>
<span><input id="event_newsletters_2" name="event[newsletters][]" type="checkbox" value="2" /><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="event_newsletters_2">Newsletter 2</label></span>
etc. etc.
```

When I create a new event or edit an event, the newsletter values are saved properly in the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specify the param `:checked`:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :newsletters,
                             Section.all,
                             :id,
                             :name,
                             :input_html => { :class => 'checkbox' },
                             :checked => @event.newsletters %>
```

Reference: [how to preselect an association checkbox using simple_form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500923/how-to-preselect-an-association-checkbox-using-simple-form?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SimpleForm you can use this:

```
<%= f.input :newsletters, collection: Section.all, as: :check_boxes %>
```